# Add/delete value from ArrayList for uniqe values

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm developing an app that uses `ArrayList` to fill `ListView`. I use custom Class for my `ListView`. I want to add/delete from `ArrayList` for my `Listview`.My aim to this app is control list item elements, if it is exist in `ArrayList` remove or if it is not exist in `ArrayList` add list item.

In order to explain my situation I have pasted my code below;

**It is my custom Class;**

```
public class NDListItem {
    String textdata;
    public NDListItem(String textdata) {
        this.textdata = textdata;
    }
}
```

It is my method for using my class. Name parameter is coming from another activity. It comes properly. I use for loop for this issue and could not afford to get what I want to do. I read some documentation and found another solution. Using equals and hash-code method for my class may be will do my job but I don't know how to do this usage.

**EDIT :**  Add some explanation and `myItems` explanation in the second code block.

```
public void addLayersection(String name) {

//MyList already defined on the scope..
//MyList looks like this
// ArrayList<NDListItem> myItems = new ArrayList<>();

    NDListItem listItem = new NDListItem(name);
  if (myItems.size() == 0) {
        myItems.add(listItem);
    } else {
    if(myItems.contains(listItem))
        {
            myItems.add(listItem);
        }
        else
        {
            myItems.remove(listItem);

        }

    }

    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**EDIT2**

I updated my Class for equals method. It works wonderfully but only work first item that I added to `ArrayList`. I want to this work for every items

```
public class NDListItem {
    String textdata;

    public NDListItem(String textdata) {
        this.textdata = textdata;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) return false;
        //if(!(o instanceof) NDListItem) return false;
        if (!(o instanceof NDListItem)) return false;

        NDListItem other = (NDListItem) o;
        if (!this.textdata.equals(other.textdata))

            return false;
        else


        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html

Comment: I could not afford to add this usage in my project.

Comment: you can't add few methods to your custom class?

Comment: I can add but this always give me some weird errors.

Comment: Is there anything else except `String textdata` in your NDListItem? If not - add `name` directly to `myItems`.

Comment: @KirillK Thanks for comment. But I'm using this class in my adapter. For my custom listview. I have to use this usage :S

Comment: that tutorial explains exactly what to do if you don't want to encounter some weird errors. there is no other way.

Comment: @salih, in any case, is it there only one field in the class?

Comment: I solved errors and when i use equals in my code instead of contains it only works first added item :) I want to work this code also work for evey items :))

Comment: still, read that tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, From the details you provided,

As there is no `.equals()` overridden method available in your Custom Class `NDListItem`

Your List going to compare object based on references, So just override `.equals()` method in your custom `NDListItem` class

Like, (pseudo code only for understanding)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {     
   NDListItem ndListItemObject = (NDListItem) obj;          
   return this.textdata.equalIgnoreCase(ndListItemObject.textdata);
}
```

Now, `.contains()` method will work on Custom Object List as you desired.

Because, your Object comparison made on `textdata` property.